# How to call angular function when click p-dialog close(X) button?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-dialog

**How to call angular function when click p-dialog close(X) button?**

> I have searched and just tried this `(onHide)="cancel()"` . But it's not working. Kindly share your solutions.

*I know we can use a `close/cancel` button to  hide the popup. But in my scenario I want to call an event when clicking the (X) button click.*

Comment: Did you fixed this issue? How you fixed it?

Comment: @mkHun Tell me your scenario what you want...Because still it's not working for me. So I hvae changed my logic .

Comment: I want to redirect to another page when click the close button.

Comment: But same code in difference machine it is working, difference is version, I am using 6.2 angular version another system angular version is 6.1? Is it a problem? I am not sure. I am going to upgrade the angular 6 to 7.

Comment: @mkHun I am not sure. May be we are getting the version problem. because If you upgrade angular, then you should upgrade Primeng version as well.

Comment: Okay. I will check and inform you.

Comment: Have you checked that it has anything to do with *ngIf  in the p-dialog tag? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000644/p-dialog-onhide-is-not-working-with-ngif?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually `(onHide)="cancel()"` works fine according to this [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/yyXbThUnlXxTUXpa0OCW/).

Comment: But in my side it's not working. May be the version is not matched?

Comment: The only way to figure that out is to see more of your code. I used latest Angular and PrimeNG in my example.

Comment: Strange, on plunker it works but in my scenario its not! All other primeng components are working though

Answer (score 2):

Try: (click)="cancel()" instead.

I had the same error but I solved it by using the click method. 
Grettings :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the above, If your `[(visible)]="myBool_1 || myBool_2"`  depends on multiple variable.

Clicking `X` will try to set the last variable `myBool_2` as false, we could leverage this by using a setter function.

so `[(visible)]="isVisible"`

```
class component {
 public get isVisible(): boolean {
    return myBool_1 || myBool_2
 }
 public set isVisible(val: boolean) {
   this.myBool_1 = this.myBool_2 = val;
   this.doSomethingOnClose() 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use two events as follows:

```
onBeforeHide: EventEmitter<any>;
onAfterHide: EventEmitter<any>;
```

use in html as

```
(onBeforeHide)="onBeforeHide()"
(onAfterHide)="onAfterHide()"
```

Refer: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/956

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onHide EventEmitter, here the (alternative working method) sample code for the ts and html.

TS:

```
import {
  ...
  ViewChild,
  ...
} from '@angular/core';
import { Dialog } from 'primeng/dialog';  

...

@ViewChild('testDialog') testDialog: Dialog; 

...

onTestDialogClose() {
  const subscription = this.testDialog.onHide.asObservable().subscribe((_) => {
    // Do the action here
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<p-dialog #testDialog></p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use a boolean to display the p-dialog with

```
   [(visible)]="myBoolean"
```

You set that boolean to true when you want to display the p-dialog
Then use the (click) event.
For instance

```
    (click)="doSomething($event)".
```

In your ts do

```
    doSomething(event) {
        // If we are clicking the close button and not something else
        if (event.target.className === "fa fa-fw fa-close") {
            myBoolean = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix, that is not documented in the docs but I found it in this [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2969). You just need to split two way binding into one way binding using `visbile` and `visibleChange` properties like this:

```html
 <p-dialog header="My dialog" 
  [visible]="showDialog$ |async" 
  (visibleChange)="handleClose()"
 >
```

Above I use Angular's async pipe to show the dialog and handleClose() method to close the dialog. In the `.ts` file I can have a service injected which is using some observable of boolean value that is changing based on some condition.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  showDialog$!: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private homeService: HomeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showDialog$ = this.homeService.displayDialog$;
  }
  handleClose() {
    this.homeService.toogleDisplayDialog();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(onHide) may not be triggered if [(visible)] is a constant.

```
<p-dialog (onHide)="close()" [(visible)]="true">
```

If this is what's causing the issue, just add a boolean initialized to true to your component.

```
<p-dialog (onHide)="close()" [(visible)]="someBoolean">
```