# p-dialog onHide not working in angular 2 component - primeng

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I'm using primeng in an angular 2 application and facing this issue [(stackoverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848250/how-to-call-angular-function-when-click-p-dialog-closex-button)

Although the plunkr provided in the accepted answer works but it doesn't in my scenario. I have a separate component that loads the  based on an input from the parent component. I want to toggle the visibility flag when the child component is closed/hidden.

Here's the code snippet

```
 <p-dialog header="Assets Management" [(visible)]="showDialog" modal="modal" [closable]="true" (onHide)="close()" appendTo="body">
          .. some content ..
  </p-dialog>
```

In component, I have:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'view-car-colors',
    templateUrl: '/view-car-colors.html',
    inputs: ['showDialog'],
    outputs: ["onCloseDialog"],
})
export class ViewCarColorsComponent {
    private showDialog: boolean = false;    //default close
    private onCloseDialog: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    public close(): void {
        this.showDialog = false;
        //emit this to its parent
        this.onCloseDialog.emit({ hasChanges: true });
    }
}
```

And finally in my parent component, I am calling it like:

```
<view-car-colors [showDialog]="showCarColorsDialog" (onCloseDialog)="onCarColorsCloseDialog($event)"></view-car-colors>
```

Where `showCarColorsDialog` is changed based on a button click.

```
private onCarColorsCloseDialog($event: any): void {
    this.showCarColorsDialog = false;
    if ($event.hasChanges) {
        //fetch the changes again
        this.getCarColors();
    }
}
```

I have used the primeng controls on multiple places and they all work fine but just has this issue so I'm sure it can't be because of the version.

Comment: yeah, that's my question. did you findout the solution? bcs still am struggling with this.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I added my answer on how I did it below alternatively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `(onAfterHide)="close()"`.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/956

Answer (score 1):

After `onHide` didn't worked, I found a workaround using getter/setter like:

In my child component:

```
private _showDialog: boolean = false;

set showDialog(_show: boolean) {
        let result: boolean = this._showDialog != _show;
        if (result == true) {
            this._showDialog = _show;
            this.onCloseDialog.emit({ hasChanges: this.hasChanges, state: this._showDialog });
        }
    }
    get showDialog(): boolean{
        return this._showDialog;
    }
```

And in parent template:

```
<!--View Car Colors Dialog In Parent Component-->
<view-car-colors [showDialog]="showCarColorsDialog" (onCloseDialog)="onCarColorsCloseDialog($event)"></view-car-colors>
```

In Component, I receive the emit event:

```
private onCarColorsCloseDialog($event: any): void {
    let result = this.showCarColorsDialog != $event.state;
    if (result == true) {
        this.showCarColorsDialog = $event.state;
        if ($event.hasChanges) {
            this.getCarColors();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! that's good. but alternately am hide the close icon and disable esc button :P :P.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement:

```
export class ViewCarColorsComponent {
    @Output() onCloseDialog: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
.
.
.

}
```

and change modal="modal" to modal="true" in html file

Answer (score 0):

use a get/set

```
public _displayDialog: boolean = false;
get displayDialog() { return this._displayDialog; }
set displayDialog(value) {
  this._displayDialog = value;
  if (this._displayDialog == false) {
    alert("hide")
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case someone added `*ngIf` as well to dialog, and as you know `*ngIf` will remove dialog from the DOM, so `onHide` is never called...I had to remove the `*ngIf` from dialog(See example below)

```html
<!------- ↓Remove this *ngIf-->
<p-dialog *ngIf="display" [(visible)]="display">
 ...
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="displayDialog" appendTo="body">
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer