# p-dialog onHide is not working with ngIf?

Tags: angular, primeng

Already SO has the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065786/p-dialog-onhide-not-working-in-angular-2-component-primeng), I tried with those solution but not working.

Actual the problem is onHide event is not triggering because of the `*ngIf`, If I removed the `*ngIf` onHide is triggering.

```
 <p-dialog [(header)]="dialogText" *ngIf="displayDlg" [(visible)]="displayDlg" 
  [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" (onHide)="close()">
```

But the problem is I am having the form inside the `<p-dialog` If I am not using the `*ngIf` I am getting the undefined error when loading the page. How can I fix this issue.?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="displayDlg">
        <p-dialog [(header)]="dialogText" [(visible)]="displayDlg" 
        [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" (onHide)="close()">
    </ng-container>
```

add your form loading logic in *ngIf of ng-container.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Solved by using a different boolean variable for the *ngIf in the p-dialog tag compared to the [(visible)] attribute.  Using the same variable for both it did not work for me.   That is the basic idea.   I did it in an object oriented way.  I won't bore you with further details.